# XLOOKUP not evaluating itself

Tags: excel, evaluation, xlookup

I have copied over 2 Excel tables from one Excel sheet to a new sheet. Now, within those tables there are existing formulas using `XLOOKUP` function which currently reference the older sheet table. As soon as I update the `XLOOKUP` function with the current sheet tables, instead of showing me the result it just shows me the `XLOOKUP` formula like this on every row:

```
=XLOOKUP([@ResourceID],Resources[ResourceID],Resources[Resource Name],"",0,1)
```

The same `XLOOKUP` works fine when it references the old Excel sheet table like shown below. It evaluates good and displays the right values.

```
=XLOOKUP([@ResourceID],WorkforcePlanningModelV4.xlsx!Resources[ResourceID],WorkforcePlanningModelV4.xlsx!Resources[Resource Name],"",0,1)
```

Why does the updated `XLOOKUP` fail to evaluate?